# Hodge-theoretic criterion for smoothness

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cohomology, hodge-theory

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of any characteristic. Is it possible to give an equivalent condition for a $k$-variety to be smooth using only the cohomology of the variety (and whatever additional functorial gadgets you manage to put on it, such as a mixed Hodge structure)?

You could probably cheat by saying something like "I put a filtration of this length if it is smooth, and a filtration of this length if it is not" but let us not do that.

I probably should clarify what qualifies as a cohomology theory. Consider the category of integral schemes proper over $k$. An acceptable cohomology theory is then a functor from this category to the category of graded vector spaces (over some field of characteristic 0) whose restriction to the full subcategory of connected schemes smooth projective over $k$ is a Weil cohomology theory (I should also say something about how Poincare duality and everything else extends to singular varieties, but I am genuinely not sure how to phrase that, maybe somebody knows a good answer). If you want, the target category can be the category of modules over some integral domain of characteristic 0 (so you are allowed to remember "the integral structure" on cohomology).

Comment: No, since e.g. the normalization of a cuspidal curve should induce isomorphisms on whatever cohomology (it gives a homeomorphism on complex points, isomorphism on etale cohomology in any characteristic etc.).

Comment: But you might be interested in Du Bois singularities. Intuitively, these are singularities which are mild enough that the obvious maps $H^i(X, \mathbb{C}) \to H^i(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$ remain surjective. Not *exactly* what you are asking for, but there's Hodge theory being used to detect mildness of singularities ...

Comment: @PiotrAchinger are the etale homotopy types of the cuspidal curve and the affine line the same?

Comment: @schematic_boi Yes. In fact, the normalization map of the cusp is a *universal* homeomorphism, and hence the induced map on etale *sites* is an equivalence.